# Error when calling PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created a PL/SQL function that is supposed to be adding a given number of records to a table with the help of `new_dept_new` sequence that I've created earlier. The function compiled successfully. But I'm getting an error when calling the function:

```
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(myfunction3(3, 'OPERATIONS', 'NEW YORK'));
END;

Error report -
ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value
```

The function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction3(
records_count_in IN NUMBER, dept_name_in IN dept.dname%TYPE, loc_name_in IN dept.loc%TYPE)

RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
IS 
thestart  TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
stopwatch INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
records_count NUMBER := records_count_in;
dept_name dept.dname%TYPE := dept_name_in;
loc_name dept.loc%TYPE := loc_name_in;

BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..records_count LOOP
        INSERT INTO dept VALUES(new_dept_new.nextval, dept_name || TO_CHAR(new_dept_new.currval), loc_name || TO_CHAR(new_dept_new.currval));
COMMIT;
END LOOP;
    stopwatch := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - thestart;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Time for processing function: ');
RETURN stopwatch;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN dbms_output.put_line('ERROR Processing Request for Department: ' || dept_name_in);
END;
```

Why is the function returned without value?

**EDIT:**
After receiving feedback from the comments I've edited the function and now the values are inserted into the table and the timestamp value is returned. I also want an application error to be raised if 0 rows were inserted.

So I did the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction3(
records_count_in IN NUMBER, dept_name_in IN dept.dname%TYPE, loc_name_in IN dept.loc%TYPE)

RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
IS 
thestart  TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
stopwatch INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
records_count NUMBER := records_count_in;
dept_name dept.dname%TYPE := dept_name_in;
loc_name dept.loc%TYPE := loc_name_in;

BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..records_count LOOP
        INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname, loc) 
        VALUES(new_dept_new.nextval, dept_name || TO_CHAR(new_dept_new.currval), loc_name || TO_CHAR(new_dept_new.currval));
    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    raise_application_error (-20001, 'ERROR Processing Request for Department: ' || dept_name_in);
    END IF;
END LOOP;
    stopwatch := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - thestart;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Time for processing function: ');
RETURN stopwatch;
END;
```

However if I'm calling the function like this and zero records are inserted, I'm not getting my custom error message.

`BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(myfunction3(0, 'DEV_OPS', 'NEW YORK')); END;`

How can I fix this?

Comment: The better question is, **why did my function compiled successfully, when it is OBVIOUSLY incorrect**? "Obviously" because a function that doesn't return a value cannot be correct. **Period.** And the answer to the better question is the `exception` block. You should never, ever use `WHEN OTHERS THEN`. The result is that whatever errors your function has will be ignored and the compiler will say "OK, successful compilation" when in fact the function may be full of mistakes. Don't feel bad; lots of people do what you did - but that doesn't make it any less wrong.

Comment: @mathguy thanks, I understood my mistake. I've edited the function so the values are inserted into the table. Also I've added the IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN raise_application_error (-20001, 'ERROR Processing Request for Department: ' || dept_name_in); END IF; right above the END LOOP; However if I'm calling the function like this and zero records are inserted, I'm not getting my custom error message. BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(myfunction3(0, 'DEV_OPS', 'NEW YORK')); END;

Comment: How does passing `records_count_in`  as 0 `raise raise_application_error`. It wont' enter the loop at all. It cannot be simulated this way . `SQL%ROWCOUNT`  will be set to 0 only if no records were inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems to be wrong with your `function`except for the `exception` block.I was able to simulate the scenario with the table and column names you used and it worked perfectly fine. If there are other issues like missing table,sequence it would not have compiled for you. So, the only reason for it to fail is your `insert` statement. It could be either *constraint* violation, length of value exceeds the *column length* limit etc.

You can make a slight change in your exception block by adding a `raise` statement.This will help you to identify the actual error in your calling program.

```
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN dbms_output.put_line('ERROR Processing Request for Department: ' || dept_name_in);
RAISE;
```

Additionally, Never run insert statements like

```
INSERT INTO dept VALUES (...)
```

It is not a good coding practice and difficult to know which order it is going to insert especially when there are many columns.

Always mention the columns explicitly

```
INSERT INTO dept ( dept_id,dname,loc)  VALUES (..,..,..);
```

Comment: I have edited the INSERT statement according to your comment and now the values are inserted into the table. But I also want an application error to be raised if 0 rows were inserted. So I added the `IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    raise_application_error (-20001, 'ERROR Processing Request for Department: ' || dept_name_in);
    END IF;` right above the `END LOOP;` However if I'm calling the function like this and zero records are inserted, I'm not getting my custom error message. `BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(myfunction3(0, 'DEV_OPS', 'NEW YORK'));
END;` How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is some exception in your function that causes your function to hit the exception block. There is no return statement in your exception block and hence the error. Add a RAISE statement to see what's causing the exception.